# Elasticsearch поиск по фонетическому слову

Tags: elasticsearch

Каким образом можно реализовать в поиске Elasticsearch поиск по фонетическому слову? К примеру, пользователь вводит

> АЙФОН

и мы находит

> IPHONE

.

Comment: Ясно, что необходимо преобразовывать слово АЙФОН на английский по правилам чтения последнего. Но никах либ не нашел для этого.

Comment: Правил чтения в английском фактически нет, есть лишь куча частных случаев с кучами исключений. Будет проще вручную прописать синонимы для всех интересующих слов